# Adjusting position of individual nodes in bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, nodes-near-coords

The labeling of the bars is sometimes behind the error bar. Lifting them all isn't elegant but I haven't found a way to adjust the positions of the individual nodes. I included the third set of bars just to show that not all bars are not labeled (if that would make a difference). Perhaps there is another way of setting the labels than the nodes near coord and point meta.

```
      \documentclass{book}
      \usepackage{caption}
      \usepackage{pgfplots}
      \usepackage{booktabs}
      \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

      \begin{document}
      \definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}
      \definecolor{gray1}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
      \definecolor{gray2}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.5}
      \definecolor{gray3}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.7}

      \begin{figure}[htb]
      \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
      \pgfplotstableread{
       x    y1  y1_err  y2  y2_err  y3  y3_err  y4  y4_err meta1 meta2 meta3 meta4
       A    100 0.1 100 0.1 81  7   87  5 a a b b 
       B    100 0.1 100 0.1 83  8   97  2 a a b a 
       C    84  2   87  2   86  4   93  1 \phantom{} \phantom{} \phantom{} \phantom{} 
        }\loadedtable
        \pgfplotsset{width=18cm,compat=1.9}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar,
        ylabel={\%}, 
        symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
        xtick={A,B,C},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=110,
        nodes near coords, 
        every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.2cm},    
        point meta=explicit symbolic,  
        ]
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
        ][black,fill=gray]table[
        meta index=9,
        x=x,
        y=y1,
        y error=y1_err,
        ]{\loadedtable};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
        ][black,fill=gray1]table[
        meta index=10,
        x=x,
        y=y2,
        y error=y2_err,
        ]{\loadedtable};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
        ][black,fill=gray2]table[
        meta index=11,
        x=x,
        y=y3,
        y error=y3_err,
        ]{\loadedtable};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit
        ][black,fill=gray3]table[
        meta index=12,
        x=x,
        y=y4,
        y error=y4_err,
        ]{\loadedtable};
       \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main technique to do this is to use the key `visualization depends on` read in the error value do some computations on it and save the result in a macro, e.g. `\myshift`.  Then you can shift each node by `\myshift`.  As your error data comes from different columns the `visualization depends on` needs to added to each plot when you load the table.  I have chosen to multiply the error by a fixed factor (`4`) to determine the shift; you may wish to use a different algorithm.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{gray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.1}
\definecolor{gray1}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.3}
\definecolor{gray2}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{gray3}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.7}

\begin{filecontents}{mytab.dat}
x y1 y1_err y2 y2_err y3 y3_err y4 y4_err meta1 meta2 meta3 meta4
A 100 0.1 100 0.1 81 7 87 5 a a b b
B 100 0.1 100 0.1 83 8 97 2 a a b a
C 84 2 87 2 86 4 93 1 {} {} {} {}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \pgfplotsset{width=18cm}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[ybar,
        ylabel={\%},
        symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
        xtick={A,B,C},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=110,
        nodes near coords,
        nodes near coords style={yshift=\myshift},
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
        ]
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit][black,fill=gray]table[
        meta index=9,
        x=x,
        y=y1,
        y error=y1_err,
        visualization depends on=4*\thisrow{y1_err} \as \myshift,
        ] {mytab.dat};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit ][black,fill=gray1]table[
        meta index=10,
        x=x,
        y=y2,
        y error=y2_err,
        visualization depends on=4*\thisrow{y2_err} \as \myshift,
        ]{mytab.dat};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit ][black,fill=gray2]table[
        meta index=11,
        x=x,
        y=y3,
        y error=y3_err,
        visualization depends on=4*\thisrow{y3_err} \as \myshift,
        ]{mytab.dat};
        \addplot+[error bars/.cd,
        y dir=both,
        y explicit ][black,fill=gray3]table[
        meta index=12,
        x=x,
        y=y4,
        y error=y4_err,
        visualization depends on=4*\thisrow{y4_err} \as \myshift,
        ]{mytab.dat};
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It seems to be a bug, as I could only get the `\thisrow` macro to work with table data in an external file.  Putting the table in a macro and passing that as in your original code just fails.

Note that blank entries in your table data should be simply `{}`.

Comment: This is indeed a bug, which has already been reported to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/109/).